# Where do I find emails sent from the Samsung Mail App using a POP3 Mail Account?

Tags: samsung, email, exchange, pop3, samsung-email

I have a Samsung Smartphone with a POP3 Mail Account on the Samsung Standard Mail App.
I need the Emails I've sent with this account in my new Exchange Account **on another device**?
I think I may be able to transfer them if I find where they are stored on my phone.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can just move messages from POP3 Profile to IMAP Profile from your favorite email app.

If not, emails are stored in /data/data/com.android.email/databases/EmailProviderBody.db .

**The non-rooting method**

1. You can get these files with [adb](https://dl.google.com/android/repository/platform-tools-latest-windows.zip) when usb-debugging is enabled in developer settings, then run from `cmd.exe`:

   ```
   adb backup com.android.email
   ```
2. Convert `backup.ab` with [android-backup-extractor](https://sourceforge.net/projects/adbextractor) after [java](https://www.java.com/en/download/help/windows_offline_download.xml) is installed:

   ```
   java.exe -jar abe.jar unpack backup.ab backup.tar
   ```
3. Extract `EmailProviderBody.db` from backup.tar with [7-zip](https://7-zip.org).
4. Convert emails to *.eml with [AndroidEmailExtractor](https://gist.github.com/rbramley/65261127dfb857b03bb6) after [Groovy](http://www.groovy-lang.org/download.html) is installed.
5. Import the *.eml files in outlook express, move the messages to imap Sent folder, sync imap with new device.

**The root method:**
(If POP3 on your new device is ok for you)

1. View the ownership and file permissions from adb shell (new device)

   ```
   adb shell
   su
   ls -lnZ /data/data/com.android.email/databases
   ```

2. Copy all EmailProvider.db* EmailProviderBody.db* to the new device (or folder database) from cmd

   ```
   exit
   exit
   adb push C:\Android\Backup\email\databases /data/data/com.android.email/
   ```

3. Restore ownership and file permissions from adb shell, where 100xx is the uid from above

   ```
   adb shell
   su
   chown -hR 100xx.100xx /data/data/com.android.email/databases
   chmod 0660 /data/data/com.android.email/databases/*
   chcon -hR u:object_r:app_data_file:s0 /data/data/com.android.email/databases
   ```
4. Reboot the device. Old emails should be restored to the new device.

Comment: I'm having the same problem, with Inbox and Sent Items, but I do not understand how to execute these instructions. A bit more detail perhaps? Step by step with images if it's possible?

Comment: You don't do this steps on the phone, but windows over those programs or CMD codes. Just need to coppy all mails from my phone. My account was deleted from the server. Only way is to copy all folders to a zip file, like backup option, but somehow Samsung E messaging app don't even have a coppy option. Will start now and hear your soon with results.