# Where and how to get POP3 emails off Samsung Phone?

Tags: samsung, backup, restore, pop3, samsung-email

I recently did a backup of my email account using the Samsung Email app on my mobile phone (Galaxy A31 model SM-A315F), as it was set up as a POP3 account, then I changed it to an IMAP account, but all the POP3 emails did not back up and restore.

Is it still anywhere on the phone? Where and how can I retrieve it?

Comment: Possible dupe: [Where do I find emails sent from the Samsung Mail App using a POP3 Mail Account?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/209820/44325)