# How can I copy emails stored in the Samsung Email app?

Tags: samsung, email, data-transfer, samsung-email

I've bought a new Samsung phone and am trying to move the email stored on my current Samsung phone in the Samsung Email app.

Samsung's Smart Switch only moves the most recent emails in each account, I want all emails moved.

These emails are no longer on the email server.

I'm comfortable installing adb or running scripts.

How can I copy emails stored in the Samsung Email app?

Comment: maybe that helps (untested) [Where do I find emails sent from the Samsung Mail App using a POP3 Mail Account?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/209820)